# error in the given code for infix to postfix conversion for input containing more than 2 operands

Tags: java, postfix-notation, infix-notation

```
  static String convert(String exp)
  {
    String result="";
    Stack s1=new Stack();
     for(int i=0;i<exp.length();i++)
      {
       if(Character.isDigit(exp.charAt(i)))
       {{
       result=result+exp.charAt(i);
       continue;
       }
       else
       {
        if(s1.empty())
        {
         s1.push(exp.charAt(i));
          continue;
        }
        else
        {
         if(check(exp.charAt(i))>check(exp.charAt(i-1)))
         s1.push(exp.charAt(i));
         else
        {
        while(!s1.empty())
        {
        String a=s1.pop().toString();
        result=result+a;
        }
        s1.push(exp.charAt(i));
        }
       }
      }
     }
    while(!s1.empty())
    {
    String p=s1.pop().toString();
    result=result+p;
    }
    return result;
  }

    static int check(char c)
    {
    switch (c) {
            case '+':
            case '-':
                return 0;
            case '*':
            case '/':
                return 1;
            case '^':
                return 2;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Operator unknown: " + c);
            }
    }
```

Here's my code to convert an expression from infix to postfix.
This code is working fine with just 2 operands..for more than 2 operands like 6+9*7 it shows
 IllegalArgumentException which I have given in another method to set priorities of operators. Please help me to clarify where am I getting wrong?

Comment: Please indent your code, it's hard to read it like that..

Answer (score 0):

1. **Indent your code**
2. In the stack trace:

   ```
   at Test.convert(Test.java:21)
   ```

   Is this line:

   ```
   if(check(exp.charAt(i))>check(exp.charAt(i-1)))
   ```

   So I think you mean:

   ```
   if (check(exp.charAt(i)) > check(s1.peek()))
   ```
3. Now "The method check(char) in the type Test is not applicable for the arguments (Object)" is raised, so parameterized your `Stack`. That is, change:

   ```
   Stack s1=new Stack();
   ```

   To (in Java 7):

   ```
   Stack<Character> s1 = new Stack<>();
   ```

Comment: one more — use StringBuilder instead concatenation strings in loop

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this exception because of your logic. Consider 1+2*3. In this case, when you get 3 below code gets executed:

```
else
{
if(check(exp.charAt(i))>check(exp.charAt(i-1)))
s1.push(exp.charAt(i));
```

And check(3) results in

```
default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Operator unknown: " + c);
```